# Keep browser window open after scraping?

Tags: python, scrapy-selenium

When using [`scrapy-selenium`](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium), how can one keep the browser window open after scraping has finished (or aborted)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding 'detach' to scrapy-selenium options?

On selenium alone it would look like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome

options = ChromeOptions()
options .add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = Chrome(chrome_options=options )
```

On scrapy-selenium probably something like this:

```
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['detach']
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work ): I don't know where to hook in when using scrapy-selenium, that's the issue.